# I want to bypass FRP , without paid softwares ,August Security Patch Removed

Tags: adb

Information of device :
Model :SM-A315F
Basedband version : A315FXXS4DWH1
One UI version : 4.1
Android Version : 12
Android Security Patch Level : August ,1,2023
Adb fail when using apps to reset frp
I can't enable usb debugging